# how to print message for authentication in cakephp

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.3

how to print message for authentication in cakephp

I wrote this statement in beforeFilter()

```
 $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                           'all'=>array(
                               'scope'=>array(
                                       'User.is_active'=>1
                                    )),
                               'Form');
```

but when I am logging with correct password and email , it is saying that they not match,
Can anybody tell me that what modification should I do to make it run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `beforeFileter` add this line

```
$this->Auth->authError = "Your Error";
```

If you don't want to display Error, write

```
$this->Auth->authError = false;
```

[Go Ahead and read some documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages)